# Import an .AI file and use some specific shapes from it in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have in Illustrator a layer with two object named objA, objB.
Is it possible to move objA once the file is loaded in the swf ?

> Manipulate some shape from a AI file in AS3.

Thx

-Leg

Answer (score 2):

i understand you want to import graphics during authortime from Illustrator to Flash?  if that's your question then yes, but you'll have to place objA and objB on different sublayers before importing to Flash.

importing an Illustrator file onto the stage/library is the same as drawing the objects using Flash, but of course Illustrator is much better for authoring vector graphics than Flash.

each object in your illustration that you want separate should be on it's own sublayer prior to importing them.  once they're imported you just simply have to convert them from a drawing object to a symbol and give it an instance name.  alternatively, during import, you can convert them to MovieClips and give them an instance name and even set their registration point (see screen shot).

to import your .AI file, simply drag it onto the stage, or select File > Import > Import to stage... or File > Import > Import to library...

also, i believe there is a way to give your illustration layers instance names inside Illustrator, allowing you to set it up for Flash or Flash Catalyst, but how to do that escapes me at the moment.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No.

Illustrator (AI format) has NO means of support over animation or SWF control. It isn't even exported, it is *imported* - the application being responsible there is Flash, not Illustrator.

You'll have to make it in the actual SWF.